# Copy libGDX project to another computer: can't find required libraries

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

I created a libGDX project with the new project setup manager. It works fine.

I copied my project files to another computer, and when I open them with Eclipse, I have several errors like

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Project 'Game-core' is missing
>   required library:
>   '/Users/me/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx-box2d/1.1.0/919bff3c5e92062ee3413f86076c089bd810b5b3/gdx-box2d-1.1.0.jar' Omega2D-core        Build
>   path  Build Path Problem

I suppose that I forgot to export something, but I'm not sure why: shouldn't it suffice to simply copy the folders form the Eclipse workplace?

Comment: Looks like its referencing a cached file in `Users/me/.gradle` so either copy that directory over, or refresh your project: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Updating-LibGDX